# Is end of execution window in Evenote Android Job ignored when enforced requierements are not met

Tags: android, android-job

I'm using [Evernote's Android Job library](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) to schedule job to run when device is online with the following code:

```
new JobRequest.Builder(DemoSyncJob.TAG)
            .setExecutionWindow(1L, SECONDS.toMillis(10))
            .setRequiredNetworkType(CONNECTED)
            .setRequirementsEnforced(true)
            .build()
            .schedule();
```

As I can observe, scheduler is waiting for the network and - when device comes online - runs the job, even if time specified as the end of execution window (in my case `SECONDS.toMillis(10)`) have passed. So my question is - is this parameter (`endInMs` in `setExecutionWindow` method) completely ignored when `setRequirementsEnforced(true)` is called?